# How to read the char string after 5 dollars sign ($) in php

Tags: php, regex, string, char

I want a php code that can read the char string after 5 dollars signs($),
example
Input:

```
ACCT_ID$ID_NUMBER$ID_TYPE$SMSC$FIRST_NAME$PROMO_CODE$MOBILE1$MOBILE2$OFFICE$HOUSE$
```

Output should be like:

```
PROMO_CODE$MOBILE1$MOBILE2$OFFICE$HOUSE$
```

Comment: Can you just split the string by $? What are your requirements? http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: yes bro can split but i need to insert some string after 5th $ sign....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These code will work ,but without regex

```
<?php
   $haystack = "ACCT_ID\$ID_NUMBER\$ID_TYPE\$SMSC\$FIRST_NAME\$PROMO_CODE\$MOBILE1\$MOBILE2\$OFFICE\$HOUSE\$";
   $needle = "$";
   $pos = -1;
   for ($i =0 ;$i < 5 ; $i++) {
     $pos = strpos($haystack, $needle, $pos+1);
   }
   $result = substr($haystack, $pos+1);
   $previous = substr($haystack, 0, $pos+1);
   $final = $previous."something to add".$result; //add something here.

   echo $result,PHP_EOL;
   echo $previous,PHP_EOL;
   echo $final,PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: bro can you also tell me how to add any string after this 5th $ sign? and combined that string again.?

Comment: see my edit. You should get some knowledge of php strings. The manual : https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.strings.php